# laravel 5 how to compile elixir with template inside node_modules

Tags: laravel-5, gulp, laravel-elixir

I have installed https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella on my application,  is there a way to link the assets to laravel elixir?

here is my template directory

```
Root
|-app/
|-node_module/
|   |-gentelella/ # -> this is my template
|-gulpfile.js
|-public/
// other laravel folders to follow.
```

Inside ./gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
});
```

Comment: What do you currently have in *gulpfile.js*?

Comment: yes i have inside the root folder and I also found a gulpfile.js inside the gentelella folder.

Comment: I mean as code, edit your post and add the JS from *gulpfile.js*.

Comment: @TheFallen I have updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');

    mix.styles([
        'node_modules/path/to/gentelella/css.css'
    ], 'public/css/app.css', './');

    mix.version('public/css/app.css');
});
```